# Derive the Carnot Efficiency without using the Carnot Cycle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, reversibility, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

How can you derive the Carnot efficiency using only properties of reversible cycles?

Comment: What do you mean deriving it without the Carnot cycle? Carnot's formula *is* the efficiency of the Carnot cycle.

Comment: The Carnot Efficiency is the efficiency for ANY reversible heat engine. I want to know if there is a way of deriving it without using the Carnot Cycle, just from the properties of reversible heat engines.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300347/optimality-of-the-carnot-cycle

Comment: Yes it is. Carnot's Theorem states that ALL reversible engines have the same efficiency. The Carnot Cycle is just one special, very simple case of a reversible engine.

Comment: @Gert dude, how right you are!

Comment: Your sarcasm is being unhelpful and obnoxious.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second law of thermodynamics.

Consider as the system a generic reversible engine plus the cold and hot sources. This is a closed and reversible system, therefore its entropy change vanishes. You decompose this change in changes due to the engine and due to the sources. The entropy change of the engine after a cycle vanishes, thus
$$\Delta S=\Delta S_{\mathrm{sources}}=0.$$
The hot source loses $|Q_1|$ at constant temperature $T_1$, whereas the cold source gain $|Q_2|$ at temperature $T_2$. Hence,
$$\Delta S=-\frac{|Q_1|}{T_1}+\frac{|Q_2|}{T_2}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{|Q_2|}{|Q_1|}=\frac{T_2}{T_1}.$$

Plug this into the efficiency
$$\eta=\frac{W}{|Q_1|}=1-\frac{|Q_2|}{|Q_1|},$$
and obtain the efficiency of a reversible engine
$$\eta=1-\frac{T_2}{T_1}.$$

Notice that we have not made any assumption about the cycle or even the agent responsible by the engine. That is in the Core of Carnot theorem. Any engine, regardless its nature, working between the same sources have the same efficiency, so it is natural that this efficiency can be calculated without any reference to the Carnot cycle which is a specific cycle followed by a specific agent (ideal gas).

Comment: wait a minute- does not the carnot efficiency represent the theoretical maximum possible efficiency of any heat engine operating between two given temperatures, rather than representing the universal efficiency of any and all heat engines operating between those two temperatures?

Comment: It represents the efficiency of any reversible engine operating between two temperatures. That efficiency happens to be the maximum possible efficiency for heat engines.

Comment: @nielsnielsen It represents the theoretical maximum efficiency of any heat engine between two sources, equivalently, the universal efficiency of all reversible engines operating between two sources. The key point here is the term reversible.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway of deriving it without the use of entropy? Because increasing entropy is derived from the Claudia Inequality, which is in turn derived from  Carnot's Theorem. Is there any way?

Comment: @user140323 The only other way I know is by calculating heats and work explicitly from the Carnot cycle diagram.

Comment: @user140323 Entropy change is what distinguishes reversible from irreversible. How can you possibly derive efficiency of reversible cycles without bringing in its definition which necessitates the concept of entropy? Also increasing entropy which is the second law of thermodynamics need not be considered as derived from some theorem, but as an extremum principle in its own right. See Thermodynamics by Callen.

Comment: Diracology, Your answer is correct and complete as it stands. The statement "The last step is to invoke Carnot's theorem which says all reversible engine working between T1 and T2 have same efficiency" is unnecessary because by definition reversible cycle is one for which entropy change of the universe is zero. So your derivation which sets total entropy change to zero is therefore applicable to any reversible cycle.

Comment: The original definition of a reversible process, without invoking entropy, is a process which can be reversed  by applying infinitesimal changes to its surroundings. From this comes Carnot's Theorem, from which comes Clausius' Theorem, from which comes the definition of entropy.

Comment: @user140323 "The original definition of a reversible process, without invoking entropy, is a process which can be reversed by applying infinitesimal changes to its surroundings." Can you make it mathematically precise so as to be useful in a derivation?