# Is Carnot cycle the only "most efficient" cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

In all the books, that I have studied so far, they say that Carnot cycle is the most efficient cycle. But why isn't any other reversible process as efficient as Carnot cycle? **Can somebody please provide mathematical explanation for why that is or isn't the case?**

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300347/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [optimality of the Carnot cycle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300347/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nuance is that the Carnot cycle is the only reversible cycle between **only two reservoirs**. There are other idealized cycles that are also reversible (i.e., that generate no entropy) but require more reservoirs.

See [da Silva, "Some considerations about
thermodynamic cycles", *Eur. J. Phys.* 33 (2012) 13–42](http://users.df.uba.ar/dmitnik/fisica4/articulos/termo/ciclos.pdf) for the math framework of evaluating engine reversibility. Note the statement *"This property makes the Carnot engine a very
special engine: it is the unique reversible heat engine functioning with only two reservoirs. (Any other cycle could be performed in a reversible way, but that would require a virtually
infinite number of thermal reservoirs.)"*

See also [Leff, "Thermal efficiency at maximum work output: New results for old heat engines," *Am. J. Phys.* 55, 602 (1987)](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ehsleff/LeffThermalEfficMaxWorkAJP.pdf) and [Leff, "Reversible and irreversible heat engine and refrigerator cycles," *Am. J. Phys.* 86, 344 (2018)](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ehsleff/Leff%202018a.pdf) for mathematical analyses of non-Carnot reversible cycles, such as the reversible Otto cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The Carnot cycle efficiency is given by

$$ζ=1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}$$

It is the most efficient because all of the heat added to the cycle occurs at a single temperature (high temperature reservoir, $T_H$) and all the heat rejected occurs at a single low temperature (low temperature reservoir, $T_L$). This minimizes the ratio  $T_{L}/T_{H}$ and maximizes $ζ$.

For any other reversible cycle that takes in heat from a series of variable temperature reservoirs and/or rejects heat to a series of variable temperature reservoirs, you would have to use the mean temperature of the reservoirs in place of $T_L$ and/or $T_H$.  That would result in a higher value of the ratio $T_{L}/T_{H}$ and lower value of $ζ$. That is because the mean value of the series of low temperature reservoirs would be a number greater than the lowest temperature reservoir of the series, and the mean value of the series of high temperature reservoirs would be a number lower than the highest temperature reservoir of the series.

Hope this helps.