# How to justify that Carnot loop for ideal gas is closed on two sides by adiabatic curves?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, carnot-cycle

I'm trying to figure out how to show that the orange curves connecting the two green curves are infact adiabatic:

[image]

The set up is that I have an ideal gas,  and  I am searching for the loop when it's operating between two temperature such that it's work maximized ([More details](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706107/understanding-the-shape-of-carnot-loop-in-the-pv-plane/706163#706163)). I can argue why two segments must be isothermal , but I can't seem to find any way to justify the two adiabatic segments.

I know that adiabatic segment have the maximum work done relative to all other standard path in the $P-V$ plane, but I am not sure how to go from that to the required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segments are adiabatic (no heat transfer) because the system needs to be brought from temperature of one reservoir to temperature of the other. This can't happen while in contact with any of the two reservoirs (the reservoir would act against it), so it happens without contact with any of them, and thus this process is adiabatic.

Such adiabatic process can be done in many ways, including irreversible ones where the process can't be represented as a curve in PV diagram, for example, sudden expansion to decrease temperature, or sudden compression to increase it. But that would not be a reversible process. Maximum possible work for given accepted heat from the hotter reservoir is achieved in any reversible process involving that accepted heat, and here it can be done by making both adiabatic processes quasi-static and also without friction. Quasi-static process can be represented by a curve in the PV diagram, and the condition of adiabaticity fixed its shape ($PV^\kappa = const.$).

Comment: Thanks Jan. I think your answer is the one I was looking for. However, one point is not clear in it to me. Could you explain, the point  "the reservoir would act against it" a bit more?

Comment: If the system is in contact with reservoir at $T_1$, then any attempt to change temperature of the system to $T_2$ will be hampered by the reservoir, due to heat conductive contact. The reservoir will "try" to maintain temperature of the system at $T_1$ by accepting/giving off heat, and it won't be possible to get all parts of the working medium to temperature $T_2$ which is necessary for the next isothermal process at $T_2$.

Comment: The issue I have is , in one of the edge we are actually dropping the temperature, so wouldn't it be efficient to keep it near the cool one to cool it off faster ? And reversely near the hot one wheen we are trying to heat it up. I actually thought of the same argument you said, but I was stuck at the point I have metioned now.

Comment: > *"wouldn't it be efficient to keep it near the cool one to cool it off faster ?"* -- What is "cool one"? The colder reservoir?

Comment: Yes the cold reservoir. The system being kept near the cold reservoir so it's cooled faster, and near hot for getting heated faster.

Comment: It would be efficient in the sense the medium gets colder faster. But that would hurt engine efficiency, because useful heat in the medium that could do work via expansion while cooling down, would instead be dumped to colder reservoir, without doing any work.

Comment: Efficiency is not about speed. In fact the slower any such real Carnot-like engine is, the more reversible its stages get and the closer it gets to theoretical Carnot efficiency.

Comment: Hi Jan, I get what you said. But for what reason must it be that being in contact with temperature reservoir reduce the efficiency? Or in general why does the speed up reduce eff

Comment: Because the faster the process, the more the working medium gets out of equilibrium and the more the process get irreversible. Energy losses are greater.

Comment: "This can't happen while in contact with any of the two reservoirs ..., so it happens without contact with any of them, and thus this process is adiabatic." The implication is unclear: without contact with the two reservoirs, doesn't imply that the system cannot arrive at the final temperature by contact with additional reservoirs at intermediate temperatures.

Comment: @GiorgioP yes. But there are no other reservoirs in the consideration.

Comment: In the Carnot cycle, there are no other reservoirs. But in that case, by definition, there are two isotherms and two adiabats. Here, the OP is looking for proof that the optimal cycle made by two isotherms should be completed by two adiabats. Therefore, the presence of other thermostats (i.e. other heat exchanges) should be proven, not assumed.

Comment: @GiorgioP Yes, except the last sentence. The "proof" suggested in my answer is valid when we are restricted to two reservoirs.This restriction can't be proven for the given isotherms, but it *is* an appropriate assumption.If we allowed for additional reservoirs at other temperatures, there would be no unique interesting solution; we could devise a cycle with arbitrarily large area that is not a Carnot cycle.This larger work per cycle would be possible with appropriate continuum of reservoirs of all temperatures between $T_1$ and $T_2$,because more heat could be extracted outside the isotherms.