# How would a heat engine with 3 bodies work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, equilibrium, heat-engine

Say we have 3 equal bodies in contact, and there is a heat engine that absorbs and emits heat to these 3 bodies and it does work to an external medium.

How would that work? I imagine that it would get to a final temperature between the 3 bodies, and it could be found with $$Q_A+Q_B+Q_C+W_{engine}=\Delta U$$

But I have no clue

Comment: Any cycle that has more than two unequal temperature isothermal stages and connecting adiabatic (isentropic) stages would be less efficient than if it was working between two temperature, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300347/optimality-of-the-carnot-cycle. Also, note Kelvin's axiom: in cycle, a single isothermal stage cannot deliver positive work from which also follows that in a cycle any number of equal temperature isothermal stages cannot deliver positive work.

Comment: You have 3 identical finite bodies at 3 different temperatures, and you want to figure out the maximum amount of work that can be extracted from them, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller no, I want to figure out the final temperature that they will be all on. But I can't explicitely say so since some dumb users here will close my question thinking it's a homework question while it isn't

Comment: on any case, I think I solved it myself

Comment: Let's see what you did.  I get the cube root of the three initial absolute temperatures.