# Relation between heat quotient and temperature quotient

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Is $$\frac{Q_c}{Q_h} = \frac{T_c}{T_h}$$ valid for any reversible ideal cycle Or just for the Carnot cycle?

Comment: what do you think and why?

Comment: I'm wondering if a machine be reversible necessarily implies in entropy variation of the surrouding equals zero. Because, if so, then this relation will ve valid for any reversible cycle, despite I believed it was only valid for Carnot's cycles.

Comment: what happens in a reversible but otherwise arbitrary cycle here is a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300347/optimality-of-the-carnot-cycle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation only makes sense if $Q_C$ occurs at temperature $T_C$ and $Q_H$ occurs at temperature $T_H$. So the heat  flows are at just two temperatures. If we also have reversibility, we must surely, by definition, have a Carnot cycle! There is no other sort of reversible cycle for which the equation could make sense.

Comment: The heats occuring in its respectively temperatures implies in a cycle made by two isothermals and two adiabatics?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean!

Comment: If we have a machine (with a generic cycle) that operates between two thermal sources with constant temperature, $Tc$ and $Tq$, can we say that the entropy variation of surroudings is $\Delta S_{sur}\geq-\frac{Q_h}{T_h}+\frac{Q_h}{T_h}$? If so, if we say that this machine is also reversible, can we say that $\Delta S_{sur}=0$?

Comment: I can't edit anymore, but it should be corrected to $\Delta S_{sur} \geq -\frac{|Q_h|}{T_h} + \frac{|Q_c|}{T_c}$

Comment: Yes, That's right.

Comment: But, as I said in the beginning, if the machine has a generic cycle, than wouldn't $\frac{|Q_c|}{|Q_h|} = \frac{T_c}{T_h}$ be valid for any reversible machine? Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: A generic reversible cycle wouldn't, surely, have only one $T_c$ and only one $T_h$. If there is only one of each, you have, by definition, a Carnot cycle.

Comment: Great answer. Other reversible cycles exist, but they use more than two reservoirs, making the equation ill-defined.